# Visual Studio 2019 Extension That Shows Errors inside the Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio

I've had to rebuild my machine lately and lost all the Visual Studio extensions I had installed.

I did have one that displayed error messages inside the code block, but for the life of me I cannot find it on the marketplace.

It does very similar things to this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexanderGayko.ShowInlineErrors

But the trouble with the extension above, is it writes the error over existing code, which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017? 2019?

Comment: Visuals Studio 2019

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexanderGayko.VarAdorner

Comment: This is a different extension by the same person above. And has nothing to do with displaying errors in the code window. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you not happy with the default `Tools`:`Options`:`Text Editor`: **Show Error Squiggles**?

Comment: I already have this option checked, it's not the squiggles I want it's the actual error message to appear in the code window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found it myself it's at the following URL

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eberthold.SteroidsVS